# How to edit and delete documents from AWS DocumentDB using MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongoose, mongodb-compass, aws-documentdb

I recently was able to connect my AWS DocumentDB cluster to MongoDB Compass so I could monitor what was going on.

The issue I am currently facing is that I can not update or delete individuals documents from MongoDB Compass; I keep getting an error saying "**Retryable writes are not supported**"

I did some research and found out that DocumentDB does not support Retryable writes, so I am hoping there is a work around for this

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding the following options to the connection string

```
&replicaSet=rs0&readPreference=secondaryPreferred&retryWrites=false
```